# Can you get a different column from a row with a MIN or MAX value?

Tags: mysql

I'm building an application with millions of rows, so I'm trying to avoid JOIN whenever possible. I have a table like this:

```
ID        category  value_1   value_2
1         1         2.2432    5.4321
2         2         6.5423    5.1203
3         1         8.8324    7.4938
4         2         0.4823    9.8244
5         2         7.2456    3.1278
6         1         1.9348    4.4421
```

I'm trying to retrieve `value_1` from the row with the lowest `ID` and `value_2` from the row with the highest ID while grouped by `category`, like this:

```
category  value_1   value_2
1         2.2432    4.4421
2         6.5423    3.1278
```

Is this possible in an effective way while avoiding constructs like string operations and JOIN?

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain why `6.5423` appears as a category 2 value in the expect results.  This does not seem to fit with your logic.

Comment: why the "avoiding constructs like string operations and JOIN"?  that makes no sense

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Of category 2, the lowest ID is 2, which has a value of `6.5423`.

Comment: @ysth The full table has more columns and tens of millions of rows. I first used multiple JOINs, but that doubled the loading time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    category, 
    (
        SELECT t2.value1
        FROM table1 t2
        WHERE t2.id = MIN(t1.id)
    ) as value1,
    (
        SELECT t3.value2
        FROM table1 t3
        WHERE t3.id = MAX(t1.id)
    ) as value2
FROM
    table1 t1
GROUP BY
    category
;
```

---

Create and fill table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `category` INT NULL,
  `value1` DOUBLE NULL,
  `value2` DOUBLE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1, 1, 2.2432, 5.4321),
(2, 2, 6.5423, 5.1203),
(3, 1, 8.8324, 7.4938),
(4, 2, 0.4823, 9.8244),
(5, 2, 7.2456, 3.1278),
(6, 1, 1.9348, 4.4421);
```

Output:

```
1   2.2432  4.4421
2   6.5423  3.1278
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach which avoids joins is to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY ID)      rn_min,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY ID DESC) rn_max
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    category,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_min = 1 THEN value_1 END) AS value_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_max = 1 THEN value_2 END) AS value_2
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    category;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

**Edit:**

The above query should benefit from the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (category, ID);
```

This should substantially speed up the row number operations.

Comment: It does give met the correct answer, but also a error: Notice in .\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#4241 - Undefined index: statement

Comment: @JMRC Then maybe your PHP script has some problem, or maybe you aren't using MySQL 8+.  What I gave above I consider the best answer without using joins.

Comment: It might have been indeed PHPmyadmin. I'll give it another try.

Comment: Unfortunately it was too slow. It took multiple minutes, but +1 because it did work on the example.

Comment: @JMRC Please try adding an appropriate index, q.v. my updated answer.